# Python pass external arguments and execute accordingly

Tags: python

python  -size big
The size is big.

python  -size big -color blue
The size is big.
The color is blue.

Currently, I am splitting the arguments by delimiter of '-' then take 2nd item of the list and print if those conditions met. Is there any better ways to do so?

Comment: please share your current code so that we would improve on that instead. that being said a robust solution would probably be using [Argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html)

Comment: You could use [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/argparse.html)

Comment: The first couple of lines read more like a Dr. Seuss story than a clear question on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There wasn't too much shared, but I think I see what you're after. You want to use [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/argparse.html) for this sort of thing:

```py
# main.py
import argparse


if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description="Helpful description here",
    )

    parser.add_argument(
        "--size",
        type=str,
        dest="size",
        default="small",
        help="The size",
    )

    parser.add_argument(
        "--color",
        type=str,
        dest="color",
        default="green",
        help="The color",
    )

    args, unknown = parser.parse_known_args()
    if unknown:
        raise ValueError(f"Unknown args: {unknown}")

    print(f"Size is: {args.size}")
    print(f"Color is: {args.color}")
```

Here's a default call:

```sh
$ python main.py
Size is: small
Color is: green
```

Here's a call with only `size` provided:

```sh
$ python main.py --size gigantic
Size is: gigantic
Color is: green
```

Here's a call with both:

```sh
$ python main.py --size HUGE --color purple
Size is: HUGE
Color is: purple
```

And you can even get help:

```sh
$ python main.py --help
usage: main.py [-h] [--size SIZE] [--color COLOR]

Helpful description here

optional arguments:
  -h, --help     show this help message and exit
  --size SIZE    The size
  --color COLOR  The color
```

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `argparse` which makes things simpler.

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

# Add your arguments here
parser.add_argument("--color", "some desc")

args = parser.parse_args()

# Access the arguments 
print(args.color)
```

So your command to execute can have the arguments included like this

```
python test.py --color "blue"
```